# Create Virtual Raster from a large number of Tiffs using OSGeo4W Shell

Tags: qgis, raster, osgeo4w

I am hoping to find a relatively straightforward way to create a virtual raster for a large set of rasters (c. 15,000 TIF files from the TQ 100K Square of OS 1-10K).

I cannot do this in QGIS. I get the following error: "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program". Presumably this is because there are too many files: it works fine for other squares with fewer files.

I have attempted copying and pasting the script that QGIS generates into OSGeo4W Shell, and running it there without success. I have run this at the root of the drive (H:>), the destination folder for the virtual raster, and the folder containing the source tifs. Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I do not have the expertise  to know what, or how to remedy it.

The script I get is: gdalbuildvrt "//..../My Documents/GIS/Datasets/Ordnance Survey/1-10,000/2018/Virtual Rasters/1-10K_TQ.vrt" "...list of files..."

Is it possible to do this through OSGeo4W Shell, or do I just need to break it down into smaller chunks and run it through QGIS?

I have tried numerous pieces of advice on here and elsewhere, e.g. https://astuntech.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ISHAREHELP/pages/14844053/Mosaic+thousands+of+raster+images, but they are either not specific enough to my situation, or require a level of understanding of script which I do not have.

Comment: that wiki page assumes you are on a unix box

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate a file containing a list of the tiffs one per line:

```
dir /b /s H:\My Documents\GIS\Datasets\Ordnance Survey\1-10,000\2018\TQ\*.tif > files.txt
```

Here you are using the standard windows `dir` command to list all the `.tif` files into a file called `files.txt`. (`/b` removes the header/footer, and `/s` makes it recursive). This allows you to avoid the command line length limit by passing that file to [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) using the `-input_files_list` option:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list files.txt 1-10K_TQ.vrt
```

Since you used a full path in the file names list you can use it anywhere and just create the vrt where you need it.

Comment: Sorry Ian, you're going to have to unpack that for me a bit more please: the tiffs are contained in the folder: H:\My Documents\GIS\Datasets\Ordnance Survey\1-10,000\2018\TQ - I've tried inserting that into the 1st piece of script you have written there, with no joy, but then I am probably doing this wrong. Please could you clarify what I should be entering here?

Comment: Still not working I'm afraid: keeps saying "The system cannot find the path specified". 

Should I literally be pasting: dir /b /s H:\My Documents\GIS\Datasets\Ordnance Survey\1-10,000\2018\TQ\*.tif > files.txt  into H:\> ?

Comment: that is it exactly - you'll need to be on h: first though

Comment: alternatively test it out in smaller steps: dir My Documents then dir My Documents\GIS etc to see where the path is wrong

Comment: I've done it from H: and tested it all out - the path seems to be correct. Do I need to replace the asterisk with something?

Comment: Do you have some tif files in there?

Comment: If it's still complaining about not finding the path, maybe try "H:\Users\yourusernamehere\Documents". The spaces in the pathname could be another culprit, you could try double-quoting the whole pathname part too like: "H:\My Documents\GIS\Datasets\Ordnance Survey\1-10,000\2018\TQ*.tif"

Comment: There is a different syntax to create a vrt from a folder: gdalbuildvrt doq_index.vrt doq/*.tif . You should just google gdalbuildvrt and check the documentation. It would be easiest if you coped your files to somewhere with a simple path and then browsed to that location within OSGeo Shell and then run the command.

Comment: Thanks All. I have tried these various options, with no progress other than that when I add quotes to the filename, the error message changes to "This operation is supported only when you are connected to the server." Which server this is I am not sure - I do not connect to a server to access these files. But at least the path seems to be correct.

Comment: I considered moving the files to somewehere with a simpler path, but my concern was that I will ultimately need to move the folder back once processed: at that point would the VR not cease to work, because the link to the files would be invalid?


I have looked at the documentation on gdalbuildvrt but I do not have the savvy to even begin to understand it I'm afraid. I was hoping there might be a simple solution for this, but perhaps I just need to find another way around it.

Comment: can you get dir to list the files at all?

Comment: Yes, that works fine - lists all the files

Comment: and you can pipe them into a file?